# Plot a shape if value comes close to moving average

Tags: pine-script

I'm very new to Pine Script so please excuse my question. I'm trying to plot a shape whenever the current price close comes within distance of 0.5% to a moving averages' value. I know how to write code but can't quite wrap my head around Pine just yet. This is what I have at the moment:

```
plotshape(close * 0.05 > sma_long, style=shape.cross, size=size.normal, color=color.red)
```

Comment: And what’s the problem you are having?

Comment: That it doesn't work.

Comment: First of all, I should remember you, that 0.05 - is 5%, not 0.5%. 0.005 is 0.5% Second, do you want plot a shape when `sma_long` in distance `0.995 <= close <= 1.005` or when close is in 20 (or even 200 if 0.5%) times greater than `sma`? Because, according to your code - it's rather the last one.

Comment: @Michel_T. Thank you! That was the right clue. So essentially in Pine Script I have to accommodate for both directions separately, is that correct? 0.05 was a typo.

Comment: yes, that's right. I think it should be similar to the next expression: `close <=  sma_long * 1.05 and close >= sma_long * 0.95`

Comment: @Michel_T. Thank you very much for your great help! I was able to figure it out. I saw this answer on other programming languages: `if (x >= 1 && x <= 100) => true`, which is the same but with a different syntax. I still have a lot of stuff to learn with Pine.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this question. Here's the answer.

```
plotshape(close <= sma_long * 1.005 and close >= sma_long * 0.995 ? true : false, style=shape.cross, size=size.normal, color=color.red)
```